# Take a screenshot of a file

Tags: excel, ms-word, command-line-interface, screenshot, libreoffice

I work for PHPOffice library.

I wish testing rendering of generated files (Excel, Word or PowerPoint & LibreOffice equivalents).

I thought generating files, opening the Office application, taking a screenshot, and verifying that there is no regression.

How can I, in command line, open a file (xlsx) in an Office application (Excel), take a screenshot and close the Office application ?

Thanks

Comment: What about converting to PDF?  There are many command line examples, for example: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/

Comment: @JimK The need is the rendering in Office & LibreOffice. Converting in PDF doesn't permit to see if the rendering in LibreOffice is good.